# torsocks segmentation fault OSX

Tags: segmentation-fault, localhost, tor, torsocks

I've installed torsocks recently using brew but could not get it working.
tor running on localhost:9050 as usual. torsocks on it's own without any arguments works fine as well, but everytime i execute command using torsocks/torify, i get segmentation fault.

*Edit: csrutil is disabled*

```
➜  ~ tor
Jul 26 15:06:33.253 [notice] Tor 0.4.5.7 running on Darwin with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1k, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma N/A, Libzstd N/A and Unknown N/A as libc.
Jul 26 15:06:33.253 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jul 26 15:06:33.256 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Jul 26 15:06:33.264 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jul 26 15:06:33.264 [notice] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jul 26 15:06:33.264 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Jul 26 15:06:33.265 [notice] Opened Control listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9051
Jul 26 15:06:33.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.4.5.7/share/tor/geoip.
Jul 26 15:06:33.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.4.5.7/share/tor/geoip6.
Jul 26 15:06:33.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Jul 26 15:06:34.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Jul 26 15:06:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
Jul 26 15:06:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
Jul 26 15:06:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
Jul 26 15:06:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
Jul 26 15:06:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits
Jul 26 15:06:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits
Jul 26 15:06:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit
Jul 26 15:06:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done

➜  ~ torsocks curl google.com
[1]    2755 segmentation fault  torsocks curl google.com
➜  ~ torify curl google.com
[1]    2763 segmentation fault  torify curl google.com
➜  ~ torsocks --version
Torsocks 2.3.0
```

**tried reinstalling with no luck...**

**/usr/local/tor/torsocks.conf is looking defaultish.**

Anyone knows anything about this?
THX a lot <3